# AMD HD Radeon 8650G + HD 8670M Dual Graphics on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I'm currently a Windows 10 user, but would like to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. According to this, the AMD 8670M (Oland) driver is supported by the open source graphics driver: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

I'm wondering if the 8650G (Richland) driver is supported as well? Also, would there be any problems with a dual graphics setup in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I don't know if AMD cards can both work without proprietary drivers.

Comment: I'm fine if only one of them can work.

Comment: Well then you'll be fine, but don't expect that you'll be able to game.

Comment: That's not a problem. I'll be dual booting with Windows 10. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you find it?